# Find available dates given start date and end date

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm pretty new to SQL SERVER and I'm trying to make some select with dates.

Table **Dates**

| StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- |
| 05/01/2021 08:00:00 | 10/01/2021 12:00:00 |
| 20/01/2021 10:00:00 | 25/01/2021 11:00:00 |

There are **2 DATETIME** pickers that the user can choose for

I would like to ask --> If a user picks `StartDate 06/01/2021` and `EndDate 08/01/2021` how could i know that they are not available days because I already have `05/01/2021` to `10/01/2021`.

Here is what I tryied

```
SELECT * FROM MyDB.dbo.Dates WHERE CAST([StartDate] as date) >= '06/01/2021' AND 
CAST([EndDate] as date) <= '08/01/2021'
```

But I get 0 records because I didn't write it good I guess, if someone could help me to think of about it would be very appreciated (if you find something missing I would be happy to help). Thank you

Comment: Pass them through as **parameters**. If you were hard-coding them, it's probably your regional settings swapping mm/dd. Also, for optimization purposes, adjust your params to beginning and end of date, rather than the column

Comment: Thank you for replying. I did not fully understand your comment... I was saying that if we execute the above query with the above table It returns **0** rows because there is no record between `06/01/2021` and `08/01/2021` but if we look at the table he can't choose `06/01/2021` and `08/01/2021` because there is alredy a record with `05/01/2021` and `10/01/2021`. I hope you undrestood I'm not very good in english sorry.

Comment: Sorry looking at it I think you have it wrong: `Dates.StartDate >= @StartDate AND Dates.StartDate <= @EndDate` It's hard to say also what you want to do about partial dates, but if your intention is to count partial days the same as full days you can convert the parameters to whole days rather than the table columns